# Codeigniter 4 Current/Active Controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

In Codeigniter 3 is possible to get current active class and method with this code:

```
    $active_controller = $this->router->fetch_class();
    $active_function = $this->router->fetch_method();
```

Are there such functions in Codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In CodeIgniter 4**

```
$router = service('router'); 
$controller  = $router->controllerName();  

$router = service('router');
$method = $router->methodName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Its worth saying those classes were never officially part of CI3 (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=fetch_class). Bearing in mind CI4 is a lot more flexible and that routes are defined more variably I would look at the routing side of things and extract it from there (https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#the-request-url).

Comment: It's not the get-right-away solution, but accepting it, since you have guided me to an answer to my problem.

Comment: Used uri_string(), to get what's current url and then used it to determine where exactly the user is. Now I got stuck with controller/method/parameters urls, but I find it I wouldn't need anything different, at least for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP `constant` or `functions` that provide you the same:

###### Get Current Function name:

```
__FUNCTION__
```

###### Get Current Class name:

```
__CLASS__
```

OR

```
get_class()
```

##### Codeigniter 4: All the above is working well otherwise use the same code that @mathan answered:

```
$router = service('router'); 
echo $router->controllerName();
```